# Customised search interface for Ebay

Tags: ebay

The Ebay API lists as a possible opportunity:

> Searching – customized interfaces for
>   searching the eBay marketplace

Are there currently any alternative Ebay interfaces of which I should be aware of?

Answer (score 2):

Not really, but http://ebay.barrycarter.info/ (plug!) might be an example of what they mean: a filtered list of items.

Comment: Sweet, I like it